# Syntax explanation of method

Tags: objective-c

Im following tutorial and i typed method like follow:

```
+(void)downlaodDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *))completionHandler{

    // Instantiate  a session configuration object
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    // Instantiate a session object
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];

    // Create a data task object to perform the data downloading
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


        if (error != nil){
            // If any error occurs then just display its description on the console
            NSLog(@" %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {

            //If no errors occurs, check the HTTP status code.
            NSInteger HTTPStatusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];

            //If it's other than 200, then show it on console.
            if (HTTPStatusCode != 200){
                NSLog(@"HTTP status code = %d", HTTPStatusCode);
            }

            //Call the completion handler with the returned data on the main thread.
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                                    completionHandler  (data);
                completionHandler (data);
            }];

        }

    }];

    //Resume the task
    [task resume];

}
```

I have 2 question:

First - in method declaration i've seen following: `withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *))completionHandler`. I have never seen construction like `(void (^)`. In my understanding of method syntax, we have arguments and type, that method should return or not, but what is that? I've never seen `void`in place like this, and what is `(^)`? I know, `^` means block, but what about that construction?

Second - in

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{

                completionHandler (data);
            }];
```

I see `completionHandler (data);`. There is round brackets, `completionHandler` is declared in top method, and data is obvious the data, we got from the URL. But what exactly that does and what is - completionHandler? When i look at `(void (^)(NSData *))completionHandler`  i think that `completionHandler` is object of `NSData` type. That make no sense for me. I guess, i just can't understand syntax correctly.

Could u please provide an explanation? I know the whole meaning of this, but this 2 chunks of code confuse me.. Thank you!

EDIT:

In  my viewController.m i have a method declared as follow:

```
-(void)getCountryInfo{


    //Prepare the URL that we'll get the country info data from.
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=Necrosoft&country=%@", self.countryCode];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    [AppDelegate downlaodDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data){

        //Check if any data returned
        if (data != nil){

            //Convert the returned data into a dictionary
            NSError *error;
            NSMutableDictionary *returnedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if (error != nil){
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }

        else {

            self.countryDetailsDictionary = [[returnedDict objectForKey:@"geonames"] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.countryDetailsDictionary);

            //Set the country name to the respective label.
            self.lblCountry.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ (%@)", [self.countryDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"countryName"], [self.countryDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"countryCode"]];

            //Reload the table view.
            [self.tblCountryDetails reloadData];

            //Show the table view.
            self.tblCountryDetails.hidden = NO;



             }

        }
    }];

}
```

There is a class method call that was described above:

```
 [AppDelegate downlaodDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data){
...// there is code pasted above
```

So, if i understand correct, `completionHandler (data);` invokation defined as follow:

```
        //Check if any data returned
        if (data != nil){

            //Convert the returned data into a dictionary
            NSError *error;
            NSMutableDictionary *returnedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if (error != nil){
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);

        }

        else {

            self.countryDetailsDictionary = [[returnedDict objectForKey:@"geonames"] objectAtIndex:0];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.countryDetailsDictionary);

            //Set the country name to the respective label.
            self.lblCountry.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ (%@)", [self.countryDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"countryName"], [self.countryDetailsDictionary objectForKey:@"countryCode"]];

            //Reload the table view.
            [self.tblCountryDetails reloadData];

            //Show the table view.
            self.tblCountryDetails.hidden = NO;
```

When data is an NSData object which we successfully download with :

```
 AppDelegate downlaodDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data)
```

Am i right?

Comment: Look for Blocks in Obkectice-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *))completionHandler`

Objective-C methods declare arguments with C typecast syntax. So, this can be thought of as:

```
withCompletionHandler:(SomeType)completionHandler
```

where *SomeType* is `void (^)(NSData *)`. This is, admittedly, ugly and confusing syntax. What it means is: block pointer for a block which takes an `NSData*` argument and doesn't return anything (returns `void`).

Consider:

```
void foo(NSData *);
```

That's clearly a declaration of a function which takes an `NSData*` argument and doesn't return anything.

Next:

```
void (^foo)(NSData *);
```

That's a declaration of a block variable named `foo` which takes an `NSData*` argument and doesn't return anything.

Now, to make it just a type, drop the name `foo`:

```
void (^)(NSData *)
```

That's the type of `foo` in my last example and the `completionHandler` argument in your code.

Hopefully that helps answer your second question. The code:

```
completionHandler (data);
```

is an invocation of the `completionHandler` block. It passes `data` as the argument to the block, which matches the known type of the block.

Comment: Thank you Ken! Now its all clear for me! I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: btw, what exactly [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                completionHandler (data);
            }]; (based on presented code)? I still not figure that out..Document says: This method adds a single block to the receiver by first wrapping it in an operation object. What does that mean anyway?

Comment: `NSOperationQueue` is a queue of operation objects (instances of `NSOperation` or subclasses). It feeds those operations into worker threads based on readiness, priority, and concurrency limits. Operations encapsulate some task and track various state. One subclass of `NSOperation` is `NSBlockOperation`, where the work done by the operation consists of one or more blocks. The `-addOperationWithBlock:` method creates an operation object (similar to `NSBlockOperation`) which uses the passed-in block as its task. It adds that operation to the queue.

Comment: thank you for detailed answer. If i understand correct. block implementation is declared in other place of code (in tutorial its declared in another class method).

Comment: The block is right there: `^{ completionHandler (data); }`. That's a block whose code consists only of invoking another block (`completionHandler`), passing in a parameter. This new block is passed to `-addOperationWithBlock:` which creates an operation object to wrap it and adds that operation to the queue.

Comment: then what (completionHandler) block does and where its defined? Sorry but i still don't got the main point.

Comment: The `completionHandler` is a block that will be passed in to `+downlaodDataFromURL:withCompletionHandler:` (*sic*) by its caller. It is a task that the caller wants performed when the download completes. It receives the downloaded data and (presumably) processes it somehow. It's a form of callback, if you're familiar with that term. The implementation of this method doesn't need to know or care what it does.

Comment: please take a look at my edited post. I really want to get this concept in my head and get full understanding, could u please tell me if i get it right?

Comment: I think you're right, although I'm not entirely sure I understood you. In your code `[AppDelegate downlaodDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data){ ... }];`, the part `^(NSData *data){ ... }` is a block that you're passing in as an argument to `+downlaodDataFromURL:withCompletionHandler:`. Within `+downlaodDataFromURL:withCompletionHandler:`, that block is referred to by `completionHandler`. The statement `completionHandler(data)` is an invocation of that block, passing the data that was downloaded. That causes your code in `^(NSData *data){ ... }` to be run.

Comment: right, as i mention, definition of that block in other place (in viewController.m) while method declaration is in appDelegate.m, therefore, method do its job on downloading data and pass task with NSOperationQueue to invoke completionHandler(data), which are declared in viewController.m. In simple words, in appDelegate we download data with that method, and in viewController we deal with data. That is what i learned with your help.